# API Gateway with Cognito and LoginWithAmazon

Tags: authentication, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, login-with-amazon

I am creating a REST API on API Gateway and want to use Cognito (User Pool) with LWA for authentication.

Anyone calling the API should be able to use their Amazon account credentials to get access token from Cognito and pass the access token while calling API gateway.

I want to know is it possible for callers to use a curl command or use postman to generate access token via Cognito? I checked that once the access token are generated we can call API gateway using Postman.

Any suggestion/idea on this would be helpful.